# Whats the most efficient pythonic way to do this :

Tags: python

I've a list `L` of size `N` where each element of the list is between `0` to `K-1`.
I want to create a 2D list `S` with `K` rows such that `r`<sup>th</sup> row contains all those indices `i`, such that `L[i] == r`.

For example if `L` was `[0, 0, 1, 3, 0, 3]`
then the new list `S` is `[[0, 1, 4], [2], [], [3, 5]]`

Solution should of course be O(N), it should also be as efficient as possible (Read : no useless append operations on list)

Comment: I think S should equal `[ [0,1,4], [2], [], [3,5] ]`, I've edited your question, fell free to roll it back but I guess it was just a typo or something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> L = [0, 0, 1, 3, 0, 3]
>>> import collections
>>> d = collections.defaultdict(list)
>>> for index, item in enumerate(L):
...   d[item].append(index)
... 
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {0: [0, 1, 4], 1: [2], 3: [3, 5]})
>>> [d[i] for i in xrange(1 + max(d))]
[[0, 1, 4], [2], [], [3, 5]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> L = [0, 0, 1, 3, 0, 3]
>>> S = map(lambda x: [], L)
>>> S
[[], [], [], [], [], []]
>>> for index, item in enumerate(L):
    S[item].append(index)


>>> S
[[0, 1, 4], [2], [], [3, 5], [], []]
>>>
```

With this solution, all indexes of `S` from `0` to `K - 1` are filled in with an empty list.

EDIT: indeed wim is right, `S[4]` and `S[5]` are not desired so I reused wim's `xrange` to make it work as desired:

```
>>> L = [0, 0, 1, 3, 0, 3]
>>> S = map(lambda x: [], xrange(1 + max(L)))
...
>>> S
[[0, 1, 4], [2], [], [3, 5]]
```

Comment: this is not the requested output though.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple but efficient way to do it:

```
K = 4
S = [ [] for _ in range(K) ]
for n, val in enumerate(L):
    S[val].append(n)
```